# IF Duplicate more than 1 counted as 1

Tags: count, google-sheets-formula, unique, counting, countif

all

I have list as below :

```
Apple
Orange
Grape 
Grape
Grape
```

I use formula : `=AND((COUNTIF(A1:A,A1)>1),NOT(ISBLANK(A1)))`.
How do I approach if I want grape also appear in the list?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? what is your desired result. Can you include that in your post?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try perhaps:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A)
```

this will give you all unique values with no duplicates